# How many possible game boards(game states) of tic tac toe n x n is possible?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

If I have board of size n x n in tic tac toe and I have used one field to put cross there like below

```
 | | | |
--------
 | | | |
--------
 | | | |
--------
 | | |X|
```

How many possible boards are in this game -> I mean to every possible end of this game. 
For instance in next move there is 15 possible boards in the next move there is 14 but they derive from those 15 boards, so is it $n!$ possible boards where $n$ is number of empty fields?

Game ends where: boards is full or there is n same figures in one line.

**Edit2:** If it is to hard can we estimate the order of magnitude? Limit from below and above(small o big O notation)?

**Edit3** Estimation from above would be calculating all game states if we end the game when the board is full.

Comment: When does such a game end? When the board is full or when there are 3 (or $n$?) in a row?

Comment: @Servaes When boards is full or there is n same figures in one line.

Comment: I have changed the tag from *Calculus of Variation*, which this question isn't, to *Combinatorial Game Theory*, which this question is.

Comment: @FlybyNight   Thank you. Could you see edit2 please? I just would like to know rough estimation for that.

Comment: Suppose two positions are reflections of one another.  Do you consider this to be two different positions, or only one?

Comment: Related: [TicTacToe State Space Choose Calculation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485752)

Comment: @MJD Two different, I wrote an application with minmax algorithm for tic tac toe and I try to estimate how much memory I will use.

Comment: Is this the corresponding OEIS? https://oeis.org/search?q=255168&language=english&go=Search

Comment: @benh: No, this includes games in progress, the other only includes completed games.  Also, the OEIS sequence appear to distinguish between different paths, this question only considers the state.

Comment: @Yoda: May it be assumed that the first player uses `X`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a total of $n^2$ places to fill. If cross starts then the number of crosses is $\tfrac{1}{2}n^2$ if $n$ is even, or $\frac{1}{2}(n^2+1)$ if $n$ is odd. The rest are circles, so the number of filled boards is
$$\frac{(n^2)!}{\left(\left(\tfrac{n^2}{2}\right)!\right)^2}\qquad\text{or}\qquad\frac{(n^2)!}{\left(\frac{n^2-1}{2}\right)!\left(\frac{n^2+1}{2}\right)!},$$
depending on whether $n$ is even or odd. This is not a very sharp upper bound.

On the other hand, for a game to finish, cross must make at least $n$ moves, and hence circle must make at least $n-1$ moves. The number of ways to do so is
$$\frac{(n^2)!}{n!(n-1)!(n-1)^2!},$$
so there are at least this many distinct ways to end, and this is not a very sharp lower bound.

Comment: It seems like you should be able to estimate the number of boards that end with a win before the board is full as well - there are $2n+2$ lines where someone could win, and the other entries could be chosen arbitrarily. You could take that further and do an inclusion-exclusion argument to count more precisely. But I feel like for Big-O purposes, 1 level deep would be enough.