# We have a randomized game of Tic-Tac-Toe?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

[image]

This is a game of 'Tic-Tac-Toe' (each cell labelled for convenience). Let's assume we have two 'dumb' AI's named P1 and P2 (i.e. Player 1 and Player 2) which fill in the cells at random. If P1 begins at *Cell A*, what is P1's chance of **winning**? What is P1's chance of **losing** (i.e. P2's victory)? And also, what is the chance of the game ending in a **draw**? Also, does where P1 begins affect its chances of victory, or is the chance of winning the same regardless of where P1 starts?

Remember that these are dumb AI's which pick cells at random, so there isn't really any intelligent playing involved, meaning each available cell is equally likely to be chosen.

(For those who don't understand how the game works, you win by filling-in either an 'X' or an 'O' or whatever you feel like either in a horizontal succession (i.e. ABC, DEF, GHI), vertical succession (ADG, BEH, CFI) or diagonal succession (AEI, CEG), regardless of the cell you begin with. After you begin the game, the other player will also fill in a cell. You take alternate turns till the game ends in a victory or a draw).

Also, this is ***not*** a duplicate question. Thank you (I'm a beginner to this topic).

Comment: It would simplify your counting slightly to exploit the symmetry of the board.  After the first play at `A`, there are eight equally likely possibilities for the second move.  But these may be grouped into five possibilities, some with twice the chance of others, based on geometric similarity.

Comment: Even without the (sensible) symmetry consideration in hardmath's comment: there are at most $8!=40320$ possible games starting at $A$. Why not just write a program to go through them all and count the outcomes?

Comment: @GregMartin: that seem to be a bit pessimistic. The following [estimate](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/817346) leads to approximately $8!/(4!)^2=70$ games.

Comment: @Fabian thus the brute force method won't be too long.  There is three possible start, center (1/9), side (4/9) and corner (4/9), and so on

Comment: @Fabian: for many ending positions (those that end in a tie or with only one player having a winning line), you're right that one only needs to check the ending position itself. For the (probably few) ending positions where both players have a winning line, we need to check the various ways of arriving at that position.